# Why can't I get the right stationary vector for this markov chain

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, matrix-equations, markov-process

I don't understand why I don't get the right stationary distribution/vector when I use the methods I know for this problem.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 3/4&0&1/4 \\ 1/3&1/2&1/6 \\ 1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

For example, if I try to solve $\pi A = \pi$ (system of linear equations), I get:

$\pi = (3/4, 0, 1/4)$

And if I try to solve it with $(\pi A)^T = \pi ^T$ (via eigenvalues and vectors) I get even weirder results.

But if I calculate something like $A*A*A*A$, I finally come to the solution $\pi = (4/5, 0, 1/5)$, which fits when I insert the values in $\pi A = \pi$

Am I missing something? Can the methods only be used if the matrix is irreducible?

Comment: You made a mistake there.  It should be $\pi=(\frac45,0,\frac15)$ not $\pi=(\frac34,0,\frac14)$.  As long as you only have one closed class you get unique left eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 1 so that is not a problem in this case.

Comment: State 2 is transient, so it has no support in the invariant distribution, leaving you to study a 2 state chain. Now the third equation reads $\pi_3=\pi_1/4$ giving $(4/5,0,1/5)$. (Including state 2 in the calculation does not hurt anything though because you have $\pi_2=1/2 \pi_2$ as the second equation which tells you it is zero.)

Comment: why does $\pi_3=\pi_1/4$ resolve in $1/5$. Is it because $x_1 = x_1$ and $x_3 = 4x_1$ and then you have to divide by the total number?

Comment: Because you also need $\pi_1+\pi_3=1$ for it to be a distribution.